# css3 : Make titled navigation menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

i am trying to make titled off canvas navigation item using bootstrap as attached image

[image]

i have tried to do it using css3 triangle by using [this](https://codepen.io/yukulele/pen/KLnhJ) link  but its not working for me ,  can you please help me with this. Following is the code for my navigation panel

```
 <a class="menu-toggle rounded active" href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </a>
    <nav id="sidebar-wrapper" class="active">
          <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
              <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Off canvas navigation</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sidebar-nav-item">
              <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sidebar-nav-item">
              <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sidebar-nav-item">
              <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sidebar-nav-item">
              <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sidebar-nav-item">
              <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Could you please share the CSS and Can you replicate your problem in a code snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

Use an SVG - use attached as a very loose reference.

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="left-container">
       <svg>
       <path d="M 0 10 L 8 10 L 5 0 L 30 10 L 0 10" stroke-width="" fill="#fff" stroke="">
    </path>
      </svg>

    </div>
    <div class="right-container">
       <ul>
          <li>menu item</li>
          <li>menu item</li>
          <li>menu item</li>
      </ul>
     </div>

 <div>
```